# SpringToolSuite : Faliure to transfer org.apache.maven.diagnostics:pom:2.0.6

Tags: spring, maven

I Have recently installed newest `Spring Tool Suite 3.4.0 RELEASE`.

I wanted to create project by: `new->spring project -> Spring MVC Project`. Unfortunatly after template is created and built I got error in my `pom.xml` which says:

> Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:pom:2.0.6
>   from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:pom:2.0.6 from/to central
>   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connection timed out to
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-error-diagnostics/2.0.6/maven-error-diagnostics-2.0.6.pom

I have internet connection and all `repo` which are included in `pom.xml` are downloaded. 
When I run my project on the tomcat server `vfabric` project is being deployed and I get my `Hello World` working.

What should I do to avoid error I am getting?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue while getting updates from maven repo.

I use these steps to resolve such issues -

Make sure you are not on a vpn or using proxy.

Right click on project -> Maven -> update project - check "Force update snapshots and releases"

If that does not work,
Go to your .m2 folder under your user. Inside that you will find a repository folder, rename or delete that and update your project again with the above steps. STS will refresh workspace and download all the jars again from maven repo.

Also try replacing your maven error diagnostics dependency to the latest version using this

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-error-diagnostics</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In case if you must use a proxy, then you will have to configure the settings file
Here is the documentation -
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html